# How do I undo "filter to this schema" in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, filter, schema

If you right click on a schema in MySQL workbench, the second context menu item is "filter to this schema". I meant to choose the first item, "Set as default schema" and missed. Now I can't see any other schemas. I tried selecting it again in case it toggles but it doesn't. Google comes back with nothing. If I reload workbench I get my schemas back, but is there a less drastic option or is this feature a one-way ticket?

Answer (score 8):

When you right-click on a database (schema) and click on "Filter to This Schema", all it does is enter the name of that database into the Schema filter box above.

Anytime a string is entered in that box, it filters the view to match the entered string.

To see all the databases again, just click the [image: X] icon or backspace out any characters entered. That will remove the filter from the view of databases.

[image: MySQL Workbench Schema Filter box]

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart your Mysql database and server. 
it will show all the schema and show all options as it is like before.